# ¿Cómo asignar valor a variable SQL con SELECT?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito asignarle el resultado de este select (que será un numero entero) a una variable, y luego, si la variable es > 0 no insertar el registro.

¿Cómo hago ésto?

```
SELECT D.ID_MOD_WEB_DETALLE    
            FROM MOD_WEB_DETALLE D
                INNER JOIN MOD_WEB A ON A.ID_MOD_WEB = D.ID_MOD_WEB 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[ORDR] AS O ON O.DocEntry = A.ORDR 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[RDR1] AS R ON R.DocEntry = O.DocEntry 
                INNER JOIN #TMP_PEDIDOS_WEB_NUEVOS_VTEX B ON B.NumAtCard = O.NumAtCard  
            WHERE   D.CODIGO = R.ItemCode
```

Gracias

Comment: Tienes la subconsulta. Crea tu T-SQL donde a) crees la variable, b) hagas la asignación, c) valides con un IF el valor de la variable y hagas lo que dices que quieres hacer. Cuál es la dificultad?

Comment: PD. Hay que asegurarse de que la consulta que muestras siempre retorne un único registro

Comment: Es probable que sea mejor hacerlo sin involucrar variables. ¿Puedes compartir el código completo? ¿Dónde vas a insertar la información? ¿Sólo se insertará este valor?

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @ID AS INT;
SELECT @ID = D.ID_MOD_WEB_DETALLE    
            FROM MOD_WEB_DETALLE D
                INNER JOIN MOD_WEB A ON A.ID_MOD_WEB = D.ID_MOD_WEB 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[ORDR] AS O ON O.DocEntry = A.ORDR 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[RDR1] AS R ON R.DocEntry = O.DocEntry 
                INNER JOIN #TMP_PEDIDOS_WEB_NUEVOS_VTEX B ON B.NumAtCard = O.NumAtCard  
            WHERE   D.CODIGO = R.ItemCode;
IF (@ID <= 0) BEGIN
  -- INSERT INTO <TABLE>
  -- VALUES (.....)
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer lo que pides tienes que utilizar variables, que se declaran de la siguiente forma (ejemplo de una variable tipo INT):

```
DECLARE @nombrevariable as INT
```

Luego debes de asignar un valor a la variable, que en tu caso es el resultado de una query: `SET @nombrevariable = ( select 1 as foo )`

Por tanto, tu consulta sería algo como esto:

```
DECLARE @numero as INT;

SET @numero = (SELECT D.ID_MOD_WEB_DETALLE    
            FROM MOD_WEB_DETALLE D
                INNER JOIN MOD_WEB A ON A.ID_MOD_WEB = D.ID_MOD_WEB 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[ORDR] AS O ON O.DocEntry = A.ORDR 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[RDR1] AS R ON R.DocEntry = O.DocEntry 
                INNER JOIN #TMP_PEDIDOS_WEB_NUEVOS_VTEX B ON B.NumAtCard = O.NumAtCard  
            WHERE   D.CODIGO = R.ItemCode  )

IF (@numero <= 0) BEGIN
    -- INSERT INTO <TABLE> VALUES(a,b,c...)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es evaluar un valor, el propio if te permite realizar esto de manera que solo tienes que hacer la comparación en el if. Pero tienes que tener dos cosas en cuenta. La primera es que tú consulta tiene que retornar un resultado. Dado que quieres comparar si es mayor que 0, no hace falta que tengas en cuenta si el resultado de la consulta es null.

`IF ((SELECT TOP (1) D.ID_MOD_WEB_DETALLE

            FROM MOD_WEB_DETALLE D
                INNER JOIN MOD_WEB A ON A.ID_MOD_WEB = D.ID_MOD_WEB 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[ORDR] AS O ON O.DocEntry = A.ORDR 
                INNER JOIN [BADAMAX_PRODUCTIVO].[dbo].[RDR1] AS R ON R.DocEntry = O.DocEntry 
                INNER JOIN #TMP_PEDIDOS_WEB_NUEVOS_VTEX B ON B.NumAtCard = O.NumAtCard

            WHERE   D.CODIGO = R.ItemCode
    ) > 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO -----
END`

La expresión que devuelva la consulta es evaluada y te permite entrar en el código del IF. Además te asguras con TOP(1), que el resultado seá único.